# C# - Not being able to use list.Count() in this scenario

Tags: c#, list, count, compiler-errors

I've been getting  this error during compile:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Count is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

about trying to use the  method Count() on a list I created that represents an inventory in my project. The list itself is public so I can't get my head around as to why this is happening... (newbie here)

```
public class Inventory
{
    private List <string> _inventory;
    public List<string> inventory {get; set;}

    public Inventory ()
    {
        _inventory = new List<string>();
        inventory = _inventory;
    }

    public void AddItem(string str)
    {
        if (inventory.Count() < 3)  //    error pops up here...
            inventory.Add(str); 
        else
            Console.WriteLine ("Your inventory is full!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you quote the exact error message?

Comment: What's the error, and does it occur at compile or runtime?

Comment: It might be slightly off topic, but can you explain why you don't use `public List<string> inventory { get; set; }`?

Comment: @Voidpaw, what benefit do you feel that change would bring to the code?

Comment: From the code provided it looks technically impossible. So, or the message is not exact or the code presented to describe the problem is not complete.

Comment: I don't see any compile or runtime error in this code.

Comment: Running your code in Linqpad shows no error - neither at compile time nor at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, I am new to this and not familiar with .Linq, so I didn't import it and using the property instead of the method did the trick.

Comment: @DavidArno I don't see why you would create a second item when the examples on MSDN just create public structs. I figured I was never too old to learn and I'd like to see his point of view

Comment: @Voidpaw I am new to C# and was experimenting around with properties. There is really has no need in this case to create that second item. Sorry for creating confusion....

Comment: @Bagongo No need to apologise, I could have just as easily missed a great reason as to why you did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using List you should use the property Count, not the method Count(). Count() is an extension method and you would need to import System.Linq in order to use it.

Comment: It does not solve the problem. In the absence of a namespace would be shown different error.

Comment: OP said "System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Count is inaccessible due to its protection level" How that's possible with his code?

Comment: @Francisco Using the Count property instead of the method actually worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could see this as possibly happening is if you've somehow overridden the Count method on List or implemented your own class for List. Did you do either of those things? If so don't and it should fix it.

Answer (score -4):

`count` is a Property not a Method.

in your case it should be

`if (inventory.Count < 3)`